# present modal view at the beginning

Tags: iphone

I'm working with a modal view for menu, which is supposed to come up at the very beginning of the application. And then, touching the button in the menu changes the view to main view...

So unlike many other modal view usages, modal view has to be pretended without a touch from main view, but must precede it...

The modal view appears successfully when called in the middle of main view by a button, but does not work if I make it appear at the beginning (by placing the

```
 [self presentModalViewController:menuModal animated:YES];
```

at the functions that are called in the early stages..)

I considered calling the main view as the modal view from menu view, but that's kind of a reversed way, so I'm not sure.
How could I implement it?
Please please help me out...

Comment: where are you placing the presentModalViewController? if you put it in the "viewDidLoad" method, it should work.

Comment: I made a separate function for calling presentModalViewController but placing it in viewDidLoad didn't work... i'm guessing it's because it crashed with main view controller...

Comment: putting it in viewDidLoad gives me "Application tried to present a nil modal view on target" error..

Comment: oh I was wrong.. putting it in viewDidLoad compiles, and log seems like it actually went thru implementing modal view, but then the app still begins with main view without showing modal view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modal view or normal view cannot be pushed on the existing view on viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear methods. As the view itself has not loaded till then.

Hence, Put a

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
      [self presentModalViewController:menuModal animated:YES];
 }
```

statement in `(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` method (as shown above) of your initial or the main view of your app.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually do this is to create a splashViewController class.  When the app delegate starts, I instantiate the splashVC, and add it to the main window. Inside the splashVC, you can put your button, and when the user taps the button, splashVC removes itself.

In appDelegate:

```
 // in didFinishLaunching
 SplashViewController *svc = [[SplashViewController alloc] init];
 [self.window addSubview: svc.view];
 svc.view.tag=kSPLASHTAG;
 [svc release];

 [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

In splashVC:

```
 // in viewDidLoad or init method
 // create your menu, add it to self.view

 // in button tap method
 [self.view removeFromSuperview];
```